# Hyperlink not working while populating Data into Excel

Tags: java, excel

I am populating URL into Excel sheet through java code. But the hyperlink is not enabled if I populate through Java code.

If I type URL into Excel sheet directly, hyperlink automatically coming. Could you please let me know why it is not coming if I populate through code.

Comment: have you your code to share?

Answer (score 0):

You may need Worksheet_followhyperlink enabled in the spreadsheet through [vba](/questions/tagged/vba). I've encountered this populating hyperlinks into Excel before.  Pop this into the sheet with the links:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_followhyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Target.Follow
    ' Any other code you might need. 

End Sub
```

Comment: There is a (very long winded) alternative to this if there isn't a huge number of hyperlinks. Workbook_Open can be added, it runs on open as you'd guess and can parse the column with the links and change them into Hyperlinks dynamically. However, you'd need a list of URLs and some logic in vba to add them, and you'd need Worksheet_followhyperlink possibly anyway! I have the code for this if needed.